# Is a FoldScope microscope suitable for plant cytogenetics?

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy, cytogenetics

I have recently been getting more interested in amateur botany, and have some background in genetics and genomics (PhD+). I have used standard light and confocal microscopes but don't have much expertise in microscopy.

I often find myself wondering what the ploidy is of some plant that I'm looking at, as I know that this is a major life history feature and genetic variant in wild plants.

I was curious whether a cheap little scope like a [foldscope](https://teamfoldscope.myshopify.com/collections/foldscope-kits/products/foldscope-individual-deluxe-kit) would be an adequate microscopy instrument for looking at the cytogenetics of a (probably rather crudely prepared) plant sample, assuming that I can come up with a suitable home protocol. (I don't currently have access to lab space.)

I have found [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/85133/can-i-use-a-basic-compound-microscope-to-analyze-the-ploidy-of-plant-chromosomes), but it doesn't really explain much about the required parameters for cytogenetic microscopy.

So:

**1) What microscopy parameters need to be satisfied to do cytogenetics?**

**2) Does a foldscope meet them?**

**3) If not a foldscope, what other cheapo scope would work?**

Comment: Foldscope has resolution of two microns, not enough for this purpose. Sorry no extra refs.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Can you comment on why? E.g. I found this: "...the size of an average condensed mitotic chromosome, which is about 6 by 0.7 microns..." That is in the same range, which might mean it's either easy, hard, or impossible, but I don't know because I don't have the background. To reiterate, what are the parameters necessary for the task?